# Setting optional system arguments via command prompt

Tags: python

I am doing a project in which I want to specify one system argument on my cmd right after the script.py. My problem is that I want to specify another argument in which is optional, and the user may or may not want to give that argument. Therefore, I am struggling how to deal with the fact that the system argument might or might not be given by the user and how to read that. If everything sounds confusing, the following text might clarify:
The user types the following on the command prompt to run the program:

```
python script.py file.txt
```

I want to add an argument which may or may not be given, like:

```
python script.py file.txt file_added.txt
```

As I read these arguments on my main script, I though that this problem would solve:

```
If sys.argv[2] is not None:
    file2 = f"\{sys.argv[2]}"
```

However, I still getting IndexError when doing that. So, is there a simple way to bypass such problem?

Comment: `if len(sys.argv) == 2:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sys.argv` holds less than 2 items, you'll get an `IndexError`. So wrap the statement around with a `try` block

```py
try:
  filename = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
  filename = None

if filename:
   # ... do something
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to accomplish this would be to check the length of `sys.argv`. If the length is 3 you'll know that a second argument was passed (3 because the first argument is `script.py`). So something along the lines:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    file2 = f"\{sys.argv[2]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `sys.argv[2] is not None` you are checking if 3rd element is None or not and that is the issue.

You are indexing outside the length of `argv` array and index error.

If you only have max 2 input then you could check the length of `argv` like `if len(sys.argv) == 3` and that means you have got both the input and then you can access them via `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use argsparse which is a built in library in python, which makes it easy to handle command line arguments. Go to the link https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html to know mor, but the basic implementation for your usecase will be like this.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Enter filenames')
parser.add_argument('-file', type=str,help='enter the file name',dest='filename1')
parser.add_argument('--optional','--op',type=str, dest='filename2',help='enter optional filename')

args = parser.parse_args()
file1=args.filename1
file2=args.filename2
```

Then in the cmd you can invoke it as

```
python script.py -filename="file1.txt"
```

or

```
python script.py -filename="file1.txt" --optional="file2.txt"
```

or

```
python script.py -filename="file1.txt" --op="file2.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, and so on. 
This should work:

```
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    readfile(filename)
```